# AWS CloudWatch logs in multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I created a lambda function in **us-east-1** and sns topic to send notifications to a slack channel.

Now I also want to use logs from a service in **us-west-2** to trigger the notifications but I can't because they are in different regions.

Whats the best way to handle this? I could just copy the Lambda function/sns topic into **us-west-2** but that seems redundant....

Thanks

Comment: do you really need to seperate service? why cant all the service be in one region?

Comment: This should help https://awstip.com/cross-account-logging-in-aws-c49653e7550e

Comment: Thanks for you input but I decided to go with separate lambda functions. Since Network Manager is only available in US West 2 and the messages being processed will be specific to that region.

Comment: You can post your solution so that it may help others in the future

Comment: thanks, will do, I wasn't certain what the etiquette was on answers

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with separate lambda functions in each region.

Since Network Manager is only available in US West 2 and the messages being processed will be specific to that region.